# the container doesn't have an ip Address, how can we connect to the mysql server container from a local client

Tags: containers, ip-address, fedora, podman, redhat-containers

I want to reproduce [this example](https://youtu.be/OabTOPOU2RU?t=272),

run a mysql container.

```
podman run -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_DATABASE=123 mysql:8.0.25
```

verify the  ip address of the container

```
podman inspect <id>
```

Then we can use any database client in the host, with this parameters to access the mysql database in the container:

- user : root
- pasword:123
- host: the-container-ip-address

my steps:

```
[chris@fedora ~]$ podman run -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123 mysql:8.0.25 
6d008dbd5ad24a49ad1a63d1ccc688bbad3af0703cbd45f0560a340bd5b722e5
[chris@fedora ~]$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                           COMMAND  CREATED        STATUS            PORTS   NAMES
6d008dbd5ad2  docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.25  mysqld   4 seconds ago  Up 4 seconds ago          practical_edison
[chris@fedora ~]$ podman inspect |grep IPAddress
Error: no names or ids specified
[chris@fedora ~]$ podman inspect practical_edison |grep IPAddress
            "IPAddress": "",
[chris@fedora ~]$
```

And ther is no ip address in the mysql container.

---

Has podman another approach about it?

Is there a better or secure way to achieve it?

information:

```
[chris@fedora ~]$ podman --version
podman version 3.1.2
[chris@fedora ~]$
[chris@fedora ~]$ uname -a
Linux fedora 5.12.9-300.fc34.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 3 13:51:40 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[chris@fedora ~]$
```

Comment: I think you could also use run without sudo, something like   `podman run -d --name mydbcontainer -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=yourpassword  -p 3306:3306 docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.25`  and `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p`. Another alternative could be using `--volume` and bind-mount the directory where the Unix domain socket is located.

Answer (score 0):

I was making a mistake.
I switched to super user using my administrative user and there the container does a ip address, maybe in the past i was only using

```
sudo podman run...
```

In conclusion, switching to super user with

```
sudo su 
insert your password
```

Now the container does have ip address there. And you can use a pipe and `grep` command

```
podman inspect <id or name> |grep IPAddress
```

```
[root@fedora chris]# podman run -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123 mysql:8.0.25 
a886b4b43446513d75734925b374c0428c7e507dcc2e73ca0cc704c7f51c8789
[root@fedora chris]# podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                           COMMAND  CREATED        STATUS            PORTS   NAMES
a886b4b43446  docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.25  mysqld   6 seconds ago  Up 6 seconds ago          suspicious_wright
[root@fedora chris]# podman inspect suspicious_wright |grep IPAddress
            "IPAddress": "10.88.0.4",
                    "IPAddress": "10.88.0.4",
[root@fedora chris]#
```